# sub item click listner in android custom gridview implementation

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

I have grid view with custom adapter implementation. On touching the grid view item, the entire item is selected. I want to perform different action on selecting different sub item in grid view.

In the below example, I have two images and one textview in the item. I want to perform different action on touching textview, image view.

Is this possible to do that in android ?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/listrow"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="66dp"
android:background="@drawable/grid_color_selector"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:gravity="fill_horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbimage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txttitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="44"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="English Channels"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/share" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The custom gridview implementation is

```
public class GridViewAdapterImpl extends ArrayAdapter < String > {
private final Activity context;
private final String[] data;
private int resource;

public GridViewAdapterImpl(Activity context, int resource, String[] fileNames) {
    super(context, resource, fileNames);
    this.resource = resource;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = fileNames;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txttitle);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    holder.imageTitle.setText(data[position]);
    return row;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView imageTitle;
}
```

The Gridview call is

```
GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
```

GridViewAdapterImpl customGridAdapter = new GridViewAdapterImpl(this, R.layout.row_list_videos, this.getVideoFiles());
gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);

gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView  parent, View v, int position, long id) { < Perform action >
    }
});

Answer (score 0):

Just add the ImageView component to your ViewHolder, and implement the listeners, see this:

```
public class GridViewAdapterImpl extends ArrayAdapter < String > {
private final Activity context;
private final String[] data;
private int resource;

public GridViewAdapterImpl(Activity context, int resource, String[] fileNames) {
    super(context, resource, fileNames);
    this.resource = resource;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = fileNames;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txttitle);
        holder.imvShare = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.share)
        // Set OnClickListener      
        holder.imageTitle.setOnClickListener(plsnTitleClickListener);
        holder.imvShare.setOnClickListener(plsnShareClickListener);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    holder.imageTitle.setText(data[position]);
    return row;
}

private OnClickListener plsnTitleClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Implement the Logic here
    }
};

private OnClickListener plsnShareClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Implement the Logic here
    }
};

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView imageTitle;
    ImageView imvShare;
}
```